# PHP clean get URL (name[]=2) not ([name%5B%5D=2)

Tags: php, forms, parameters, get

I know this can be done, but I'm unsure what the best solution is.

Essentially, when I select a checkbox, it will submit the form. This will update the URL through GET, and in effect update the URL.

My URLs are like: `http://example.com/products?options%5B%5D=2&options%5B%5B=4`

However, I want the URLs to look like: `http://example.com/products?options[]=2&options[]=4`

What options do I have?

Comment: why do you WANT the url to be like this ? , it will be parsed correctly .

Comment: Do you mean that the URLs show up like this in a browser's location bar, or that you receive them like this in PHP? The latter can be resolved by doing `rawurldecode( $url );`, for instance. The former is browser specific, I believe and thus out of your control (unless you only want it to show in your own browser). I believe some browsers (Firefox and Vivaldi for instance), sometimes, show URLs unencoded in their location bar (but encoded when I copy them to the clipboard), but I haven't figured out which conditions must be met for this to happen.